# Bubble Sort Not Returning List

Tags: python

I've written this bubble sort program, and when I run it the console prints 'return', but the list is not returned, and I have no idea why.

```
def bub_sort(ol):
    print'function start'
    s=0
    for x in range(1,len(ol)):
        print'in floop'
        if ol[x]>ol[x-1]:
            print'swap'
            ol[x],ol[x-1]=ol[x-1],ol[x]
            s=s+1
    if s>0:
        print'restart'
        bub_sort(ol)
    else:
        print'return'
        return ol
```

got a message that said my questions a duplicate, the other question forgot to return.

Comment: You need to return `bub_sort(ol)` (4 lines from bottom)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were not returning from the recursive call.

```
def bub_sort(ol):
    print 'function start'
    s = 0
    for x in range(1, len(ol)):
        print 'in floop'
        if ol[x] > ol[x-1]:
            print 'swap'
            ol[x], ol[x-1] = ol[x-1], ol[x]
            s += 1  # Python has the increment operator. 
    if s > 0:
        print 'restart'
        return bub_sort(ol)
    else:
        print 'return'
        return ol
```

P.S.
There is no need in recursion in bubble-sort.